# How can I hide my UIRefreshControl only when fetching data is complete (in Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alamofire, uirefreshcontrol

I have a UITableView and recently I added a pull to refresh feature.

So far the code looks like this:

```
@IBOutlet var tview: UITableView!
var currentDate: NSDate = NSDate()

override func viewDidLoad(){

    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "last updated on \(currentDate)")


    tview.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
    tview.addSubview(refreshControl)
}

func refresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {

    refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "last updated on \(currentDate)")

    fetchRequests()

}
```

As you can see I'm calling a function `fetchRequests()` inside the refresh control function, also I'm setting the attributedTitle there to show the user last time of the update.

My function `fetchRequests()` calls a webservice and fetches the data asynchronously:

```
func fetchRequests(){
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://mywebservice", parameters: ["username": username])
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:

                self.items.removeAllObjects()
                if let jsonData = response.result.value as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                    for requestJSON in jsonData {
                        if let request = SingleRequest.fromJSON(JSON(requestJSON)){
                            self.items.addObject(request)
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                                self.tview.reloadData()
                                self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
                                self.currentDate = NSDate()
                            })

                        }
                    }
                }
                //self.tview.reloadData()

            case .Failure(let error):
                print("SWITCH ERROR")
                print(error)
            }

    }
}
```

and I want to hide the refreshControl when the refreshing is done.

This line:

```
self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
```

inside of the `success` case in fetchRecords doesn't work. How can I refer to the refreshControl from there and end it in case of success? Also, currently I commented out the line at the very end of fetchRecords:

```
//self.tview.reloadData()
```

because I believe/hope that reloading takes place inside `dispatch_async` - is that good assumption?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing wrong here is your refreshControl object is local and is available only in viewDidLoad so even if you are using in fetchRequest() it will not work. Pass your refreshControl object to fetchRequests function. Try below thing:

```
func refresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "last updated on \(currentDate)")
fetchRequests(refreshControl)
}

func fetchRequest(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
  //existing code....
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                            self.tview.reloadData()
                            refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
                            self.currentDate = NSDate()
                        })
}
```

If you move your enter fetchRequests func inside func refresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) will also work.

Comment: Thanks, but I just realized two things here - the first one: `self.tview.reloadData()` runs multiple times because it's in the loop and refreshes as many times as there are fetched records, after each record refreshes the table view, so I cannot end refreshing the refresher there, because it's gonna be called xx times, I should do `endRefreshing` only once after the loop is done - how can I achieve that?

Comment: The other thing is that I created it locally because there is already a refreshControl in the UITableViewController and my class inherits it: `class UserList: UITableViewController {`so I didn't know how to use refresh controller from that class...

Comment: Move the dispatch block outside and after the for loop and see if its working. What is SingleRequest here for, is it another service call?

Comment: no, it's just creating a structure for future use, no more service calls :)

Answer (score 0):

While service is calling on background thread, you cannot refresh UI. when you get response then do parse and Userinteface changes inside of dispatch_get_main_queue.

```
func fetchRequests(){
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://mywebservice", parameters: ["username": username])
        .responseJSON { response in
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:

                self.items.removeAllObjects()
                if let jsonData = response.result.value as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                    for requestJSON in jsonData {
                        if let request = SingleRequest.fromJSON(JSON(requestJSON)){
                            self.items.addObject(request)

                                self.tview.reloadData()
                                self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
                                self.currentDate = NSDate()


                        }
                    }
                }
                //self.tview.reloadData()

            case .Failure(let error):
                print("SWITCH ERROR")
                print(error)
            }

    }
})
}
```

Comment: but isn't that what I'm doing now when calling `self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()` inside of ` dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{`? Because if so, then it unfortunately doesn't work...